# get the minimum column between columns values pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, minimum

i have a dataframe with x,y,z columns and with 3 X columns and 3 Xd columns and i want to  get the minimum Xd column with his X in a new column called id.

```
df:
x  y  z  a ad b  bd  c  cd
4  8  1  1 2  2  8   3  5
7  5  6  1 6  2  3   3  1
7  3  5  1 9  2  4   3  7

result:
x  y  z  id 
4  8  1  1 
7  5  6  3 
7  3  5  2
```

Comment: What do you mean _"with 3 X columns and 3 Xd columns"_. There's already an 'x' column, and there's `a ad b  bd  c  cd`. Do you mean columns with a 'd' in the name? So "ad, bd and cd"? If I understand correctly, you want a new column 'id' to be created based on the minimum value of the columns 'ad', 'bd' and 'cd' but to use the value from 'a', 'b' and 'c' respectively?

Comment: yes by Xd columns i mean ad bd and cd

Comment: whats ur spark version?

Comment: spark 2.4.5 . .

Comment: @shreder1921 could there be 2 minimums as in `ad:8, bd:2, cd:2` or will there always be one unique minimum?

Answer (score 2):

Try this, using **`arrays_zip`**, higher order function **`filter`**, and **`array_min`**.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn("zip", F.arrays_zip(F.array('a','b','c'),F.array('ad','bd','cd')))\
  .withColumn("id", F.expr("""filter(zip,x-> x.`1`=array_min(array(ad,bd,cd)))"""))\
  .select("x","y","z", (F.col("id.0")[0]).alias("id")).show()

#+---+---+---+---+
#|  x|  y|  z| id|
#+---+---+---+---+
#|  4|  8|  1|  1|
#|  7|  5|  6|  3|
#|  7|  3|  5|  2|
#+---+---+---+---+
```